# Minimizing Area With Given Volume

Tags: geometry, optimization

*Among all cylindrical cans of volume = 1l, determine which one has the smallest surface area.*

I know it's optimization but don't know where to begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write an equation for the volume in terms of diameter and height.  Write an equation for surface area in terms of diameter and height.  Solve the first for one variable, plug into the other to get area in terms of one variable.  Differentiate the area with respect to the variable you have left, set to zero ...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

You have two formulas that use the radius $r$ and the height $h$ of the cylinder.

One formula is for the volume and one is for the surface area.

You know the volume equals 1, so you can write an equation in $r,h$ and re-arrange it to get one of them in terms of the other, say you choose to write $h$ in terms of $r$.

You can then substitute for $h$ in the formula for surface area $S$. This gives you a function that uses a single variable $r$. You will need to find point at which  this function reaches a minimum. You can do this by finding a point where the gradient is zero, or numerically by plotting and estimating.

Assuming you have found the surface area and $r$ at the minimum, you can then evaluate $h$ from the expression derived from the volume constraint.